# How does the Bulkwrite operation in Mongodb work?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I wanted to do a bulkwrite on my MongoDb, the Collection on which I am using the bulkwrite is very simple.

What I am not sure about is weather it would be right for me to use bulkwrite.
I have the following questions:

1) One if I do a bulkwrite operation is it atomic?

2) Will bulkwrite write do all the updates simultaniously or can there be delays between the writes?

```
    bulkArr.push({
            updateOne: {
                        "filter": { "_id": input[i].variantId },
                        "update": { $inc: { "stocks": -quant } }
                        }
                 });
```

Answer (score 3):

**`bulkwrite` operation, is it atomic?**

From the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/write-operations-atomicity/)

- a write operation is atomic on the level of a single document, even if the operation modifies multiple embedded documents within a single document.
- When a single write operation (e.g. `updateMany()` or `bulkWrite()`) modifies multiple documents, the modification of each document is atomic, but the operation as a whole is not atomic.

**Will `bulkwrite` write do all the updates simultaneously?**

- Not really, The `{ ordered : false/true }` parameter specifies
  whether `bulkWrite()` will execute operations in order or not. By
  default, operations are executed in order.
  [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/#bulkwrite-write-operations-executionofoperations)
- Also in `bulkWrite()` operations of the same type (e.g. multiple
  inserts) may be grouped together and sent to the server, Which
  happens in batch sizes not exceeding 100,000 writes.

Comment: So, if i am only using UpdateOne operation and that too of size not more then 20 then I can  assume that bulkWrite() happens at the same time?

Comment: Yes, they'll be sent to server at the same time and will happen in the order. But since an `updateOne()` is a write operation, and WT engine uses document level locking, write on same document (if any) will happen one after the other.

Comment: @ambianBeing What about two different documents?